# What is the best way to redirect a www subdomain within a grails webapp

Tags: grails, redirect

I don't have access to any of the underlying architecture, so within my Grails webapp I have to be able to perform the redirect. When requests come in for http://www.scriptynote.com I need to return a 301 redirecting to http://scriptynote.com . I'm assuming there is some way to do this within the UrlMappings file? Thanks for any help out there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a filter, e.g. `DomainFilter` where you can check if there's www as subdomain, and if so, redirect to http://mysite.com

Comment: The code was a little tricky, but that works pretty well. Thanks!

Comment: @Johnathon feel free to provide your implementation for the benefit of others.

Comment: I've posted a little writeup on exactly what I did on [my blog](http://www.obviouslyblatant.com/2011/05/grails-subdomain-redirects.html)